# Difference between Model.offset().limit() and Model.limit().offset()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I don't understand the reason for doing `Model.limit(6).offset(5)` when we have to get 6 elements starting from the 6th index. I think that it should be `Model.offset(5).limit(6)` since we first have to tell the index from which we have to start retrieving the elements and then limit the search to the number of elements passed as argument to limit, and not the other way round.

Answer (score 11):

The thing is you mistakenly suppose that the order of chained rails methods matters. In fact, it does not. Unless the *real execution* method is called, all these methods just change the internal query that is being prepared:

```
> User.limit(6).class
#⇒ User::FriendlyIdActiveRecordRelation
> User.offset(5).class
#⇒ User::FriendlyIdActiveRecordRelation
```

That said, the order just does not matter, unless one calls the execution method, like `each` (directly or via methods like `to_a`, `map`, etc.) or `pluck`.

```
> User.limit(6).offset(5).to_sql
#⇒ "SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  LIMIT 6 OFFSET 5"
> User.offset(5).limit(6).to_sql
#⇒ "SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  LIMIT 6 OFFSET 5"
```

Comment: `all` doesn't trigger the query. `each` does.

Comment: Damn, indeed, why on the Earth `all` does not? What could be the reason to call `all` on a relation without triggering the query? Rails suck.

Comment: Now it's a way of getting an "empty" query for later customization. `products = Product.all; products = products.where(query1) if cond1; products = products.where(query2) if cond2`, etc. It is, in fact, ambiguous as to what `.all` on a relation should mean? Is it "get me all items fitting this criteria" or "disregard all previous criteria and get ALL records"?

Comment: "What could be the reason to call all on a relation without triggering the query?" - no reason. That's why nobody does this :)

Comment: Kind of goes hand in hand with your answer: Something that throws a lot of people is in IRB, rails seems to auto-execute queries because it usually immediately needs to display the results. It's the displaying of the results that triggers the query (an *execution* method), not the calling of the method. So doing anything that prevents showing the results of the query (calling `.to_sql` or `.class` or even just doing `; nil` after) stops the query from executing, not because those do anything special, but because rails just doesn't need the result right away and so doesn't execute the query.

Comment: The reason to use `all` is when it's the only thing in the query i.e.you want all the records, but only if you actually start to view them. Without `all` you're just left with the the model name which just refers to the class, not to an ActiveRecord result set.

Answer (score 3):

The two are equivalent. The SQL is generated by ActiveRecord when you evaluate and get the results from it. Use `.to_sql` to see the SQL that gets generated:

```
[1] pry(main)> User.offset(6).limit(5).to_sql
=> "SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` LIMIT 5 OFFSET 6"
[2] pry(main)> User.limit(5).offset(6).to_sql
=> "SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` LIMIT 5 OFFSET 6"
```

Answer (score 0):

The sql query generated by both cases mentioned in your question is same and hence they produce same results. So basically there is no difference in the order of using offset and limit for the same model.

```
>> Model.offset(5).limit(6).pluck(:id)
   # SELECT  `model`.`id` FROM `model` LIMIT 6 OFFSET 5
   # [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

>> Model.limit(6).offset(5).pluck(:id)
   # SELECT  `model`.`id` FROM `model` LIMIT 6 OFFSET 5
   # [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```